# How to create a scalable multi-line button in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

A `Button` in Godot can only hold a single line of text. I can overcome this limitation by placing `RichTextLabel` node inside the button.

Now the button can contain more lines of text, but its height doesn't change automatically when more lines are needed. Instead the text just overflows:

[image: screenshot of button]

Of course I can manually resize the button to be higher, but I'd like this to happen automatically depending on the amount of text inside. Specifically, I'm generating a list of these buttons programmatically and showing inside a `HBoxContainer`, with some buttons having longer and other shorter text.

Is there a way to achieve this with Godot layout tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Button` is in a `Container`, it is in control of its `rect_size`. The best we can do is specify a `rect_min_size`. There is no layout preset to have a `Control` depend on children `Control`. So, to answer the question as posted: **No, we cannot achieve this with Godot layout tools.** We need some scripting.

---

We need to set the `rect_min_size` for the `Button` depending on the `RichTextLabel`. We can ask it for the height of its content with `get_content_height`. Which also means we need to set the width beforehand. However, it will not update right away when we set the text (we are going to use `yield`).

---

Apparently you don't want the `Container` to control the height of the `Button`. If that is the case, I think you can remove all the flags from `size_flags_vertical`.

About the width, since as I was explaining before we need to set the width to get the height… I suggest you let the `Container` expand the width of the `Button` as much a posible. Which mean setting both the Fill and Expand flags on `size_flags_horizontal`.

Then, with the `RichTextLabel` properly set to take as much width of the parent `Button` as possible, you can read it height, and use it to set the height of the `rect_min_size` of the `Button`.

---

One more thing: you want to set the mouse filter of the `RichTextLabel` to Ignore or Pass, or it will prevent pressing the `Button`.

---

This is the code I came up with:

```
var b := Button.new()
b.size_flags_vertical = 0
b.size_flags_horizontal = SIZE_EXPAND_FILL
add_child(b)

var l := RichTextLabel.new()
l.mouse_filter = Control.MOUSE_FILTER_IGNORE
l.set_anchors_and_margins_preset(Control.PRESET_WIDE)
l.text = "Some\nMultiline\nText"
b.add_child(l)

yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
b.rect_min_size.y = l.get_content_height()
```

---

> I'd like this to happen automatically depending on the amount of text inside

Sadly changing the text does not resize, nor change the minimum size of the `RichTextLabel`. And `RichTextLabel` does not have a "text changed" signal. Nor "bbcode text changed" signal. Furthermore, it might not be feasible to intercept these properties (see `append_bbcode` et.al). *It is proabaly easier to do with a regular Label.*

Anyway, what I'm going to suggest for this is to make a `Control` that wraps the `RichTextLabel`, offers whatever interface you actually need, and in any method where you change the text, afterwards, you do the equivalent of this:

```
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
b.rect_min_size.y = l.get_content_height()
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped a lot. I also had some trouble attempting to set a margin around the RitchTextLabel. Ended up placing a MarginContainer between Button and RitchTextLabel and also adding it to label height in the min_size update code: `b.rect_min_size.y = l.get_content_height() + VERTICAL_MARGIN * 2`

Comment: Also, it seems that the size calculations won't work when a control is hidden. Initially I created these buttons inside a hidden container, which was shown at the end of an animation. Changed my code around to create the buttons right when they need to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

(Godot 3.x)

Without using scripting, it is also possible to achieve the same goal by wrapping both nodes as sibilings within a container, for example a MarginContainer. Enable the RichTextLabel's `fit_content_height` property, which will result in the label expanding the container's area as much as necessary, which will in turn resize the Button.

Answer (score 0):

(Godot 4.1.1)I try to realize the same function today,you can achieve this by using nodes:

1. Create a `PanelContainer` and add a button node along with a label inside it. You can adjust their sizes until you are satisfied.
2. Set the label's AutoWrap Mode to "Word (Smart)".
3. Adjust the size of the `PanelContainer` to your desired dimensions.

Now you will notice that when you resize the `PanelContainer`, both the button and the label will dynamically adjust their sizes to fit within the `PanelContainer`. I hope this is helpful for anyone reading.