# Font not rendering properly in Godot

Tags: fonts, game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

I am trying to use a font in Godot, and it is posing problems. The font is [Karmatic Arcade](https://www.1001fonts.com/karmatic-arcade-font.html).

Here are the font settings in my theme:

[image]

Here is how it looks in the editor:

[image]

And here is how it looks in-game. Notice how there are more lines, and a few transparent pixels as if antialiasing or filter is turned on.

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here?? I have similar results with other fonts, but not all of them.

Comment: This seems to be bug in Godot. Feel free to open an issue [on github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues).

Comment: @Theraot I really hope that’s not the case. The only other font I could get working does not suit the game at all.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for in the font, but I'll mention that you can get an outline effect on any font: set font shadow color, and change shadow as outline. And since the font you picked has a block style, I'm going to suggest you have a look at the retro style fonts from [ZX Origins](https://damieng.com/typography/zx-origins/), they are free to use under attribution. And while I'm at it, I'll also mention that Godot supports woff (not woff2) fonts, which often are lighter than ttf.

Comment: I do believe it is a bug because I installed the font on my PC and it looks correct on other software. However, it is something in particular in that font that is triggering it. I also see a similar artifact on the website https://www.1001fonts.com/karmatic-arcade-font.html when set to very large font size (tested in Opera and Chrome).

Comment: Yep, I can confirm the font is made like that (which is inefficient), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onuSl.png - so we are talking of a pixel rounding bug - Sadly the eula do not allow modification, so we can't legally fix the font.

Comment: @Theraot Thanks for your help! As for using font shadowing, that didn’t seem to be available for buttons. Have I missed the setting or is there just no way to do it for buttons?

Comment: Yes and no. There isn't the option for buttons, but you can make a button with a label inside. In fact, I recently answered something similar to that, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71344048/402022